# In Puerto Rico, during the Settlers phase, are players required to pick a plantation

Tags: puerto-rico

In Puerto Rico, during the Settlers phase, are players required to pick a plantation? Do they have the option to skip picking a plantation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, the players are not **required** to pick a plantation.

From the rules, emphasis mine:

> The player who chooses this role may take either a quarry tile as his privilege or one of the face-up plantation tiles and place it on any empty island space on his player board. Afterwards, each other player, in clockwise order, **may** take one of the face-up plantation tiles (not a quarry tile! - exception: construction hut) and place it on any empty island space on his player board.